# Display an image as I manipulate it

Tags: c#, image-processing

I am writing a C# program to do some scanning of the pixels in an image. This is for a program I am only going to run maybe 5 times so does not need to be efficient.

After reading each pixel I want to change it's colour and update the display of the image so I can see the scans progress and what it is finding, but I can't get anything to display. Has anyone done something like this before or know of a good example?

Edit:
The code I am trying to use at the moment is.

```
void Main()
{
    Bitmap b = new Bitmap(@"C:\test\RKB2.bmp");
    Form f1 = new Form();
    f1.Height = (b.Height /10);
    f1.Width = (b.Width / 10);
    PictureBox PB = new PictureBox();
    PB.Image = (Image)(new Bitmap(b, new Size(b.Width, b.Height)));
    PB.Size = new Size(b.Width /10, b.Height /10);
    PB.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
    f1.Controls.Add(PB);
    f1.Show();
    for(int y = 0; y < b.Height; y++)
    {
        for(int x = 0; x < b.Width; x++)
        {
            if(b.GetPixel(x,y).R == 0 && b.GetPixel(x,y).G == 0 && b.GetPixel(x,y).B == 0)
            {
                //color is black
            }
            if(b.GetPixel(x,y).R == 255 && b.GetPixel(x,y).G == 255 && b.GetPixel(x,y).B == 255)
            {
                //color is white
                Bitmap tes = (Bitmap)PB.Image;
                tes.SetPixel(x, y, Color.Yellow);
                PB.Image = tes;
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Can you add some code to show what you are doing so far?

Comment: Is this a WPF app, or something else?

Comment: WinForms? Using `PictureBox`?

Comment: Have you looked into using shaders?

Comment: [MSDN, Bitmap class, SetPixel property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.bitmap.setpixel%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).A simple solution could use as suggested [the PictureBox control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.picturebox.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You need to separate the image processing action and the update action. A good start would be to create a Windows Forms project, add the PictureBox control to the form and a button. Bind the button to an action and in the action start the processing. Then the update process will be visible. When your code is changed to this, then the final transformation should be visible:

```
void Main()
{
    Bitmap b = new Bitmap(@"C:\test\RKB2.bmp");
    Form f1 = new Form();
    f1.Height = (b.Height /10);
    f1.Width = (b.Width / 10);
    // size the form
    f1.Size = new Size(250, 250);
    PictureBox PB = new PictureBox();
    PB.Image = (Image)(new Bitmap(b, new Size(b.Width, b.Height)));
    PB.Size = new Size(b.Width /10, b.Height /10);
    PB.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
    PB.SetBounds(0, 0, 100, 100);
    Button start = new Button();
    start.Text = "Start processing";
    start.SetBounds(100, 100, 100, 35);
    // bind the button Click event
    // The code could be also extracted to a method:
    // private void startButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    // and binded like this: start.Click += startButtonClick;
    start.Click += (s, e) =>
    {
       for(int y = 0; y < b.Height; y++)
        {
            for(int x = 0; x < b.Width; x++)
            {
                if(b.GetPixel(x,y).R == 0 && b.GetPixel(x,y).G == 0 && b.GetPixel(x,y).B == 0)
                {
                    //color is black
                }
                if(b.GetPixel(x,y).R == 255 && b.GetPixel(x,y).G == 255 && b.GetPixel(x,y).B == 255)
                {
                    //color is white
                    Bitmap tes = (Bitmap)PB.Image;
                    tes.SetPixel(x, y, Color.Yellow);
                    PB.Image = tes;
                }
            }
        }
    };
    f1.Controls.Add(PB);
    f1.Controls.Add(start);
    f1.Show();
}
```

After the change the result (with my test image) looks like this:

[image: test form]

Comment: He didn't mention whether this is WinForms, WebForms, Console or something else.